# Hide asp.net panel on button click by using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to hide a asp.net panel on click a button.

JavaScript and controls I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPanel ()
    {
        document.getElementById("<%= pnlCombinedPdf.ClientID %>").style.display = "none"; 
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="ShowPanel()"/>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlCombinedPdf" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <fieldset>
                <legend class="SubSectionHeading">Merge PDF</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnMergePdf" runat="server" Text="Merge PDF"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </asp:Panel>
```

But the problem is it does not show the panel after clicked the button. Please help me make it visible on click.

Comment: *"I'm trying to hide a asp.net panel on click a button...the problem is it does not show the panel after clicked the button"* - that's because you are *hiding* it when the buttons clicked. If it's some sort of toggle behaviour you are after just toggle the `display` property from `none` to `block`.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change your jquery code:

```
function ShowPanel ()
{
   document.getElementById("pnlCombinedPdf").style.display = 'none';
        return false;
}
```

that's all

Answer (score 0):

Use `display = "block"` to show and `display = "none"` to hide

```
function ShowPanel ()
{
    document.getElementById("<%= pnlCombinedPdf.ClientID %>")
            .style.display = "block"; 
}
```